# Detect what exact phone was connected to rpi

Tags: usb

I'm trying to develop small app detecting when/which phone was connected / disconnected to rpi and than base on that take some actions 
it should work with both android and apple phones

I know how to detect if something was connected to USB but I don't know how / if its possible to detect exact phone (unique Id - eg imei or serial)

High level functionality I'm thinking of
- phone registration (store unique number in local db) 
- phone connected to usb :
  * check if it is "known" phone, then do something 
 * if unknown do Notting

Can somebody please advise if this is possible / where to start?

** EDIT **
This will be just USB cable connection Rpi-Phone. 
Only to 'authorize' user that way (and keep Phone charging). 
I do not need send anything / exchange data etc.

Ideally this should work without need phone unlocking

Comment: How are you planning to connect the phone to the Raspberry?

Comment: You could parse the output of `lsusb` to get, eg., the manufacturer and model USB ids.  You can also get that and other info from **udev** (probably including the `mei`, which I believe is used to create individual device paths in `/sys`).  A udev  hook could also be used to log the information (much of which is logged by the kernel and/or udev already).

Comment: Thanks will check this. I can get vendor id, but Im looking to get something which is unique for device so I can recognize 'registered' phone even if same model will be connected

Comment: How are you planning to connect the phone to the Raspberry? USB or BT or WiFi tethering?

Comment: Just USB cable connecition. Only to 'authorize' user that way. I do not need send anything / exchange data etc. Ideally this should work without need phone unlocking

Answer (score 2):

For Android phones, you can install `adb` on your RPi and run

```
adb shell dumpsys iphonesubinfo
```

This will return a data block containing the IMEI (international mobile equipment identity) number of your device. This is guaranteed to be unique for legitimately produced phones.

There are [scripts](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/194167/how-to-get-imei-number-from-adb-command) you can use to extract the IMEI value from the Android info block.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry. Will this work also if Android phone is not in debug mode / unlocked ?

Comment: @Maciej You have to enable USB debug mode to use `adb`, otherwise how would you know your phone charger isn't spying on you? If by "unlocked" you mean unlocked bootloader, then no, this is not required.

Comment: No other option than that?  It would be hard to convince users to enable debugging  just for this purpose.